The gcc compiler can recognize the function semantics of free and make optimizations. Why and how does it do it?
In the following code, apb and apb->amp are both pointers, pointing to a malloc address.
The phenomenon is that apb->amp=NULL will be optimized and will not be executed, but when I remove free(apb), the assignment to apb->amp will not be optimized.
if (apb) {
    if (apb->amp) {
        free(apb->amp);
        apb->amp = NULL;
    }
    free(apb);
}

I checked the optimization options of gcc and found through experiments that it was caused by the optimization option "-ftree-dse":

-ftree-dse
Perform dead store elimination (DSE) on trees. A dead store is a store into a memory location that is later overwritten by another store without any intervening loads. In this case the earlier store can be deleted. This flag is enabled by default at -O1 and higher.

I know that there is a problem with the logic of this code. After apb is released, the address pointed to by apb can no longer be used.
The problem is (I am very curious about this): how does the compiler know the semantics of the free function and optimize it for this kind of situation? Can the compiler also recognize the semantics of other functions and optimize them?

Can you post an expanded example that we can copy-and-paste into Godbolt? (That said, is it anything like this?)

The compiler is permitted to do anything that cannot be detected by a program that follows the rules of C. In this case, there is no way that a program that follows the rules of C can detect whether or not apb->amp = NULL actually happened, because the memory for abp is later freed, so abp->amp becomes indeterminate.

@RaymondChen I think the question is, if free there were just replaced by any other arbitrary C function, this optimization cannot be performed, and it seems the compiler makes a special case for free to make this optimization possible. OP seems to be interested whether the compiler can be instructed  to somehow optimize his own myfree() the same way.

I built an example on Godbolt, in which removing free(apb) or -fno-tree-dse will not lead to apb->amp being optimized. But I found that -ftree-dse alone cannot optimize apb->amp, and -O1 must be added for apb->amp to be optimized..https://godbolt.org/z/MxnYqn6xx

Clause 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage." You ask "Can the compiler also recognize the semantics of other functions and optimize them?" Yes, the compiler can recognize the semantics of any function in the standard library.


how does the compiler know the semantics of the free function and optimize it for this kind of situation? Can the compiler also recognize the semantics of other functions and optimize them?

The free function has specified semantics in the C standard. The compiler can simply use this to make assumptions about the semantics of this specific function, either by special handling this specific function hard-coded in the compiler or by using some compiler builtin or attribute that is attached to the declaration of free in the C library to indicate its specific behavior.
Compilers use the specification of functions in the C standard library for special handling of optimizations in other cases as well, whatever cases the compiler developers thought were worth it to implement special handling for.

Is there any documentation that explains this in detail so I can identify possible optimizations in advance?

@hello GCC documents a list of functions (without any details on applicable optimizations) here.

First of all, you have to realize that your code is 100% equivalent to this:
free(apb->amp);
apb->amp = NULL;
free(apb);

The relevant part in the standard is C17 7.22.3.3:

The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available
for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs.

Basically free(NULL) is a well-defined no-op.

Next we have to realize that once we call free with a pointer parameter, the pointed-at object has reached the end of its life time (6.2.4 and 7.22.3) and from there on the contents of that object has become indeterminate. Indeterminate meaning that it can literally have any value and the value need not be consistent from read to read.
As you noted, the apb->amp = NULL; line is nonsense and poorly-defined, as it writes to an object after freeing it.
But even without the first free(apb->amp); line, the compiler would still be allowed to optimize away the apb->amp = NULL;! Because it is still pointless - why write anything there if we are going to free() it directly afterwards anyway? The value of apd will become indeterminate anyway and you probably have no other references to the memory location of apd->amp present. Then that memory location is lost to the program.
That's why you see the optimization happening or not depending on if the final free() is there.

"your code is 100% equivalent to this" - Why do you say that? The outer if(apb) guard means the expression apb->amp in free's call-site won't be evaluated if apb == NULL thus avoiding a segfault/accessviolation, no?

I understand what you mean. The code logic is problematic, but the compiler is able to recognize the semantics of the free function and optimize based on this semantics. I am very curious about how the compiler does this and whether the compiler can also recognize the semantics of other functions and optimize them. I am worried that the compiler's optimization behavior will conflict with my code logic and cause problems.

@hello "I am worried that the compiler's optimization behavior will conflict with my code logic and cause problems.": The compiler only performs optimizations that won't change the observable behavior of the program. If your program uses the C standard library functions only in accordance with their specified semantics, then there is nothing to fear. That's the only valid way to use them anyway.
